# cons of linked server providers not running in "allow in process"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

what are the cons of having linked server providers not running in "allow in process"? SQL box crashed due to oracle provider crashing and it provider was running in "Allow in process", now have been advised to un-check allow in process.

Answer (score 1):

That option limits the datatypes you can access through the linked server - you'll not be able to access `text` / `ntext` / `image` columns through an externally instantiated linked server, nor row spilling `( MAX )` columns.  Not a huge loss, generally.